How to disable hibernate seeding/dropping schema in @SpringBootTest?
I am using @SpringBootTest in one of my tests.
When I run the test it passes but it is throwing some errors in the logs about dropping schema.
I would like to turn off the manipulation of schema as this is in just a unit test.
I have tried to do this with my test application.yaml file:
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        repositories:
          enabled: false

I have also tried with the test annotations
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml", "spring.profiles.active=test"},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2, replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MyTestClassTest {}

It still attempts to DROP tables

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table if exists customers.customer_alias CASCADE " via JDBC Statement
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:246)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:128)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:114)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:157)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1168)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:919)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:409)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)


Your yaml configuration:
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        repositories:
          enabled: false

is not correct, the spring.jpa.properties section is resposible for configuring particular JPA provider native properties, please check org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties. In your case you actually want to configure org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties and the configuration should look like (not sure where repositories should be placed since we do not use it):
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none


I found a way to do this by mocking the related classes
@MockBean
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
@MockBean
public OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor;
@MockBean
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

Let me know if you find a better way!
